# Destroy an array that is not allocated with 'new'

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

Let's say i have initialized an array in C++ and then i pass it another array, in order to initiliaze it.

```
int number_of_stored_values_in_Base_Array = sizeof(BaseArray)/sizeof(int);
int MyArray[number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray];
memcpy(MyArray, BaseArray, sizeof My_Array);
```

Now, I want to pass another array to the `MyArray`. Or destroy it completely and redo the process. Can I use `delete` on it, considering I have not initialized it with `new`?

What are my options?

Comment: 1. *"Can I use delete on it"* No. Try it and observe a crash (most likely). 2. Avoid manually calling `new`/`delete`, prefer containers. 3. Plain arrays can't be resized, if that's what you're asking. 4. `int MyArray[number_of_stored_values_in_MelodyArray];` is illegal in standard C++, because the size is not a compile-time constant. 5. Use `std::vector`, which can be resized, and it's size doesn't have to be a compile-time constant. 6. Avoid `memcpy`, prefer the safer `std::copy`.

Comment: ***What are my options?*** My advice is to switch and use `std::vector` instead of arrays that are a fixed size at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

`delete[]` does two things:

1. Calls the destructor of each array element
2. Returns the memory to the heap.

If your array is not allocated dynamically, then step two is not required or even possible.

For local non-static arrays, the destructors will be invoked automatically when the array goes out of scope, and the memory is recovered by adjusting the stack pointer.

For statically allocated objects, the destructor is invoked on process termination, and the memory returned to the OS.

In your case, for an integer array, there is no destructor, so it is only a matter of what happens to the memory.  Destruction is the process of object termination and resource recovery.  The memory itself is not "destroyed" - it is simply available for reuse.

In this case however, if you want to reinitialise the array with new data, you simply copy more data, just as if you were reassigning a variable - there is no destruction involved.

Comment: The new array i want to pass it to, is not of the same length of the previous array that i passed it to.... Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @user1584421 • "*Is there a solution to this?*  **Yes**, it is called `std::vector`.

Comment: @user1584421. Built-in arrays have fixed compile-time constant length.  If the length needs to be variable, then clearly that is the purpose of dynamic allocation ( whether directly or managed by a container class as Ejay suggests).  A clumsy solution is simply make the array large enough for the largest requirement and maintain the length in a separate variable.  However the most appropriate solution would require more context than the tiny fragment you have provided.

Comment: @user1584421 also that requirement is not mentioned in your question.  It looks like an X-Y problem.